# avoid callback hell with foreach method for formatting Json

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

My code works but i think it's not efficient, may be there is a more efficient way.
I have a Json (data.json):

```
{
"Testaments":[
    {
        "Books":[
            {
                "Chapters":[
                    {
                        "Verses":[
                            {
                                "ID":2,
                                "Text":"Au commencement, Dieu créa les cieux et la terre."
                            },
                            {
                                "ID":2,
                                "Text":"La terre était informe et vide: il y avait des ténèbres à la surface de l'abîme, et l'esprit de Dieu se mouvait au-dessus des eaux."
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

i want transform key object in uppercase, (i don't want use regex):

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const url = "./data.json";

var camalize = function camalize(str) {
    return str
        .toLowerCase()
        .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+(.)/g, (m, chr) => chr.toUpperCase());
};

fs.readFile(url, "utf8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    changeName(obj);

    obj.testaments.forEach((elem, ind) => {
        changeName(elem);
        obj.testaments[ind].books.forEach((elem2, ind2) => {
            changeName(elem2);
            obj.testaments[ind].books[ind2].chapters.forEach((elem3, ind3) => {
                changeName(elem3);
                obj.testaments[ind].books[ind2].chapters[ind3].verses.forEach(
                    (elem4) => {
                        changeName(elem4);
                    }
                );
            });
        });
    });

    function changeName(obj) {
        for (const property in obj) {
            const newName = camalize(property);
            obj[newName] = obj[property];
            //console.log(typeof obj[newName]);
            delete obj[property];
        }
    }

    console.log("finish");

    fs.writeFileSync(`export/export.json`, JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
});
```

i doesn't want to make a callback hell with the foreach method,
is the a more efficient method to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using a recursive method?

MDN Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion

Example here: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-recursive-function/

Comment: You say "i want transform key object in uppercase" but you seem to want to make it camel case? Do you want MYLONGKEY or myLongKey or MyLongKey?

Comment: yess camel case

Answer (score 0):

Change object properties recursively:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const url = "./data.json";

var camalize = function camalize(str) {
    return str
        .toLowerCase()
        .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+(.)/g, (m, chr) => chr.toUpperCase());
};

fs.readFile(url, "utf8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    changeName(obj);

    function updateKey(obj, k) {
        const newName = camalize(k);
        obj[newName] = obj[k];
        delete obj[k];
        return newName;
    }


    function changeName(obj) {

        for (const k in obj) {

            if (typeof propValue === 'object' && obj[k] !== null && !Array.isArray(obj[k])) {

                changeName(obj[k]);

            } else if (Array.isArray(obj[k])) {

                const newName = updateKey(obj, k);

                obj[newName].forEach(el => {
                    changeName(el);
                });

            } else {

                const newName = updateKey(obj, k);
            }
        }
    }

    console.log("finish", JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));

    fs.writeFileSync(`export/export.json`, JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
});
```